# How do I redirect url to specific url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have urls like as below

```
1.https://www.examples.com/demo-url/first-demo-url
2.https://www.examples.com/demo-url/second-demo-url
```

There are multiple urls like as above. Now I want to redirect these URLs to

```
https://www.examples.com/demo-another-url
```

I can do these redirection by writing multiple 301 redirection in `.htaccess` file. But I want it should redirect in single 301 redirection.

like as

```
 Redirect 301 https://www.examples.com/demo-url/* https://www.examples.com/demo-another-url
```

Is this possible?

Comment: URLs `https://www.examples.com/demo-url/first-demo-url` are real files OR pages? kindly confirm once.

Comment: These are pages.

Answer (score 0):

We can only assume that "-demo-url" is a fixed string which can be used to recognize such requests? If so that probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?demo-url/.+-demo-url /demo-url [END]
```

Or, if it is the `/demo-url` folder which may act as recognition anchor that would be an approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?demo-url/.+ /demo-url [END]
```

If you can *not* name such a string pattern that can be used to recognize such requests then there obviously is no way you can implement a general rule.

This uses the rewriting module provided by most installations of the apache http server. It allows for much more flexibility than the alias module which provides the `Redirect` directive.

As said the rewrite module needs to be loaded and rewriting has to be enabled for that location (http host). You should prefer to place such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. Only if you have no access to that you should consider using a distributed configuration file (often named ".htaccess").